# Is it enough if I use the "snow-leopard" tag for a question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, asking-questions

Is it enough if I tag a question [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard), or should I always use [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard) together [mac](/questions/tagged/mac)?

I can imagine that [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) would be used when I want to specify the hardware I am interested to, as in questions that involve the hardware used (for example, a question about a software driver). It is also true that any Mac OS should run just on Mac hardware, and specifying the hardware is in normal cases not necessary.

Are there any specific cases where both the tags should be used, and only the OS tag is not enough?

Comment: The tag info might need to be enhanced a bit: [snow-leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/snow-leopard/info) and [mac](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mac/info).

Like on Super User, mac [is documented to be used for Apple hardware](http://superuser.com/tags/mac/info) (not to be confused with [mac-address](http://superuser.com/tags/mac-address/info)). Questions about the OS are tagged [osx](http://superuser.com/tags/osx/info), or more specific like [osx-snow-leopard](http://superuser.com/tags/osx-snow-leopard/info) et cetera. I don't know the rules on SO though.

Comment: I agree with @Arjan but could you explain a little bit more your question, that would help give a more complete answer to your question. Very rarely questions can only be tagged with one topic.

Comment: @Trufa I expanded the question. I understand that "mac" is probably used as a general tag; it is easier to look for questions tagged "mac", rather than looking for questions tagged with each OS tag. Apart that reason, in which cases should I use both the tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your intent is to just classify information, then [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard) would probably be enough if the hardware is irrelevant to your question.  However, you should also consider that people follow specific tags.  Use as many relevant tags as you need to get the attention of people who might be able to answer the question.